# Invoke appClip from specific URL endpoint

Tags: ios, swift, apple-appclips, apple-app-site-associate, associated-domains

we've configure Associated Domain with `appclips:<domain>` in app and AASA file at that domain. configure meta tag as well for Card display. App clip card is working fine.

now question is, can we make it as it will display only at some specific URL endpoints. for ex. display appClip card only for `<domain>/someEndpoint`.

let's say domain is `example.com`, then it should show appClip card only for `example.com/someEndpoint`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve it by only applying meta tag to that specific end point.

as per apple documentation for banner [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners)

> To add a Smart App Banner to your website, include the following meta tag in the head element of each page where you’d like the banner to appear: